# Drools in NetBeans - setup instructions?

Tags: java, netbeans, drools

I intend to use Drools to set up a business rules logic system for my Java web project in NetBeans. However, the setup instructions on the official [documentation](http://docs.drools.org/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html) and [other tutorial sites](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jboss-drools-tutorial-beginners/) are for Eclipse. How do I set up Drools in NetBeans?

Comment: I think that has been asked before. Did you use that thing that finds things on the web?